# Simple Rails 3 CMS Gem/Plugin?

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Can anyone recommend a simple, lightweight CMS gem or plugin for Rails 3 that can easily be embedded into an existing app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found  [Refinery CMS](http://refinerycms.com/) to be easily emebddable into my app (with some modifications).

Comment: Just to back this up, I'm in the process of creating a new app using RefineryCMS as a CMS to manage all the static content on the site (including page inserts etc). So far, it seems to be working well. I've had to do a bit of customisation, but it's all come together well. Only one minor issue as far as I'm concerned: You have to be VERY careful about your testing, as Refinery hijacks the user journey if the CMS has not yet been set up.

Comment: Refinery is nice but might be trouble for existing applications. It uses devise and if you already use devise it's rather complicated to integrate into your existing application.

Comment: Refinery has been a mess in my experience. Too much for lightweight, too little when you need plugins etc.

Answer (score 22):

I think you might find this useful: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa

It's specifically built to be a CMS plugin for your existing Rails 3 app.
Sorry for the shameless plug :)

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/browsermedia/browsercms 
BrowserCMS: Humane Content Management for Rails

BrowserCMS is a general purpose, open source Web Content Management System (CMS), written in Ruby on Rails. It is designed to support three distinct groups of people:

- Non-technical web editors who want a humane system to manage their site, without needing to understand what HTML or even Rails is.
- Designers who want to create large and elegantly designed websites with no artificial constraints by the CMS.
- Developers who want to drop a CMS into their Rails projects, or create CMS driven websites for their clients.

Comment: Thank you for the link, this is awesome CMS! I tried it - it has good architecture and easy to extend.

Answer (score 5):

Rich CMS is another: https://github.com/archan937/rich_cms

There's also CopyCopter for Rails from Thoughtbot: https://copycopter.com but it's more for managing copy than managing full page content

Answer (score -3):

Best CMS till date

MCMS

```
gem install mcms

rails g mcms install
```

please check it

Comment: Why do you think it is the best CMS, what are its advantages?

Comment: fyi, I tracked down the source for this at [link](https://github.com/mindfire-solutions/mcms).  It has not been touched in 8 months as of May 2013, and I counted a total of 1 test.