# Rails: a good way to modify simple static pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, edit, administration, static-pages

Is there a way to allow admins to modify the content of simple static pages?

I know I can create a "Pages" model with attributes like "Title", "Content", "Images" etc, and make administrators modify them. But is there a gem for such a thing?

Comment: It seems you're looking for a CMS gem. [Here's a good list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782988/simple-rails-3-cms-gem-plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a different kind of solution which offered me a more completed way in modifying static pages.

Since pages could be different than simple text I used [Mercury](http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/) editor. Watch the demo in the page. There is a good [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor) about that but **don't follow it too strictly** since something is changed in the new versions(for example the update method is saveUrl while in the cast is called saveURL).

**Watch out!**: the github project is [this](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury), there is another one on github but it didn't work for me.
Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

[Copycopter](https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-server) was created for this sort of thing. Watch the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter).

Comment: I'm very new to rails so just a question to see if I got it:

@stephenmurdoch Copycopter application would become my admin interface, wouldn't it? And administrators will have to change pages content, by searching in that application what they want right? How can I make them retrieve just the content they want?